# Could anyone locate where the Devi Purana contains the following verse about Chaitanya Mahaprabhu?

Tags: identification-request, chaitanya, devi-bhagavata-purana

[This blog post](http://www.harekrsna.com/sun/editorials/03-13/editorials9941.htm) lists out verses from various Smritis that contain predictions of Sri Chaitanya Mahaprabhu. The following verse is said to be from the Devi Purana.

> Nama-siddhanta-sampatti
>
> Prakashana-parayanah kvacit
>
> Sri-krishna-chaitanya-
>
> Nama loke bhavishyati

**Meaning:**

"The Lord will again appear in this world. His name will be Sri Krishna Chaitanya and He will spread the chanting of the Lord's Holy Names.

Could anyone locate where in Devi Purana the above verse is found?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be anywhere related to Devi Bhagavatam which I don't think talks about Namasankirtana. Do you have any additional information like the blog you saw this verse or anything?

Comment: @Surya Read the text 29.http://www.harekrsna.com/sun/editorials/03-13/editorials9941.htm

Comment: Devi Purana is different from Devi Bhagavatam. Maybe you can edit the question.

Comment: @Surya you edit if you think so

Comment: @Surya but when I googled Devi Purana, the results of Devi bhagavatam only shown

Comment: @Surya But Devi Purana is Devi Bhagavatam

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury But there happens to be another text called Mahabhagavata Purana which also is called Devi Purana, hence there is a confusion.

Comment: @Surya Oh...sorry...I wasn't aware of that. I take back my words.

Comment: @Surya Do you know about The MahaBhaagavata Purana, or the Devi Puraana. As you said in the last comment. Kindly impart the knowledge to us.

Comment: @AnuragSingh unfortunately apart from the name I don't know anything about Mahabhagavata Purana.