# Where in Matsya Purana the following verse about Chaitanya Mahaprabhu located?

Tags: chaitanya, gaudiya-vaishnavism, matsya-purana

As per Gaudiya Vaishnavism websites, the below verse is said to have spoken by Krishna in Matsya Purana:

> Mundo gaurah su-dirghangas 
>  Tri-srotas-tira-sambhavah
>   
>  Dayaluh kirtana-grahi
> Bhavisyami kalau-yuge
>
> Meaning: In the age of Kali, I shall advent where the three rivers meet. I shall have a shaven head. I shall have a golden complexion. I will be very kind and always chant the holy name of Krishna.

Where this verse is located?

Comment: Krishna is definitely mentioned in the Matysa Purana.  His life story is told including the story of the Syamantaka gem.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Really? Krishna as a first person narrator?

Comment: Yeah, Krishna does speak in the first person in the Matsya Purana, for instance in the course of the Syamantaka gem story.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I edited the question

Comment: You earlier also posted question- [Where is mention of Chaitanya in Devi Puraanam?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21277/could-anyone-locate-where-the-devi-purana-contains-the-following-verse-about-cha) Probably this question is also from that same article as mentioned by you in Devi Puraanam question. Some of them are very doubtful and are probably interpolations.